# Should react front end and spring backend be on the same port?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, web, model-view-controller

1. I couldn't find any resource on whether the front end and back end should be on the same port for my personal project.
   a. Run React front-end(port 3000) Then Java Spring back-end (both on same port)<---- works
   b. Run Spring back-end. Then run React front-end <---- doesn't work
   Why is that the case? Is the a difference between running front end/back end first? Should the two be on the same port?
2. What is the proper way to close a react app on Mac? Ctrl-c doesn't kill the process. I have to manually kill my react script using kill -9 PID.

Comment: The answer to "why is that the case" is "because you didn't configure it otherwise."

Comment: 2.) what are you using to run the react app? usually it's a dev server like webpack, which can be stopped like any other terminal process

Comment: Using npm. How should I stop it? I have to use kill-9. Is there a better way of stopping it?